# Why did these bullets hurt Wonder Woman?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, wonder-woman

I was reading this [Is new-52 Wonder Woman bullet proof?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123359/is-new-52-wonder-woman-bullet-proof)   The question was:

> Are there any instances of **regular** bullets piercing Wonder Woman's skin in specifically the New 52 (post-Flashpoint) continuity?

The [answer by](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129124/29106) [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus-howze) is brilliant and perfect.

As it's been a while since I last read the new 52 Wonder Woman, but from what I could recall is this:

[image: Hades hitting Wonder Woman]

**Wonder Woman, new 52 issue#8**
The pistols belong to [Eros](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Eros_(New_Earth)) and were used by [Hades](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hades_(Prime_Earth)) to attack Wonder Woman because he wanted her to stay with him.

The question is:

**Why were the bullets from the pistols of Eros able to penetrate through [bracelets of Wonder Woman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81742/does-wonder-woman-need-to-use-her-bracelets)(and armour) and hurt her?**

> I calmed my curiosity by thinking that since Eros is son of [Hephaestus](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hephaestus_(Prime_Earth)), so he could have made him weapon powerful enough to pierce anything!!

Comment: Well you started off with Thaddeus praise, so chances are you'll have a brilliant and perfect answer today.

Comment: Not just a gun and those are not bullets. Those are the upgraded weapons of Eros, god of love (no more stupid arrows). Love conquers all. Nothing can stop it. Not even Wonder Woman... Eros, the God of Love, is the son of Ares and Aphrodite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What you are seeing is being taken out of context. That's not strictly a gun and those are not bullets. Nor is she being "hurt".

[image]

- Think of this as a subversion of the ancient myths. Those are the upgraded weapons of **[Eros, God of Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eros)** (no more stupid arrows). Eros, the God of Love, is the son of Ares and Aphrodite. Love conquers all. Nothing can stop it. Not even Wonder Woman...
- During the event, Hades was willing to trade Wonder Woman to gain access to **[Eros' weapons](http://wonder-woman.wikia.com/wiki/Eros),** the Pistols of Love. Considering they have the power to affect even gods, they would be a fine weapon to have in an arsenal of the God of the Underworld. (A god nobody likes, let alone loves.)

[image]

*Eros and his Pistols of Love (Get your minds out of the gutter.)*

Comment: Ok, so is this(struck with {Roman}Cupid's arrows) why she "changes" and keeps on reassuring that she loves him till the very end. (Although the marriage melodrama was becoming a bit clumsy on her part).

Comment: Yes, I remember that she's still alive, changed but perfectly ok.